# Converting MP3 albums into MP4 videos for YouTube

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video

This is a quick script that helps me to convert MP3 files from my CDs into videos I can upload on YouTube. It is intended for personal use, so no input error checks. I am creating a silent video using OpenCV, combining MP3s using pydub, then put audio and video together using ffmpeg.

I am happy with the resulting videos. The code looks a bit naive, but introducing more complex structures is probably an overkill given the simplicity of the task.

This code is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/Yulia5/Python/blob/master/YoutubeVideos/youtube.py).

```
import os, codecs, datetime, glob
import cv2, pydub, PIL # these packages need to be installed
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw

# get filenames with given extensions from a given directory and all directories inside it
def get_filenames_with_extensions_recursively(directory_name, extensions):
    result = [] 
    for extension in extensions:
        path_pattern = os.path.join(directory_name, '**', '*.' + extension)   
        result += glob.glob(path_pattern, recursive=True)
    return result

# Score function for default audio sorting: directory containing the file, 
# then the number of the track, then the name of the file
def default_func_sort_audio_files(audio_name):    
    try:
        audio_mediainfo = pydub.utils.mediainfo(audio_name).get('TAG', None)
        track_str = audio_mediainfo['track'] 
        track_nb_str = track_str.split('/')
        track_nb = int(track_nb_str[0]) 
    except:
        track_nb = -1
    return (os.path.dirname(audio_name), track_nb, os.path.basename(audio_name))  

# Resize image, add subtitles and save it. 
# Returns the filename of the resulting image (including the path)
def add_subtitles(image_filename, 
                  temp_folder,
                  width, 
                  height, 
                  subtitles, 
                  font, 
                  sub_colour, 
                  sub_bg_colour, 
                  sub_indent_x):

    # make a blank completely transparent image for the rectangle
    with PIL.Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 0)) as img2:
        # get a drawing context for it
        draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(img2)

        # create the background coloured box
        max_length_subtitles = 0
        for subtitle in subtitles:
            sub_size = font.getsize(subtitle)
            if max_length_subtitles < sub_size[0]:
                max_length_subtitles = sub_size[0]
        sub_bg_right = max_length_subtitles + 2 * sub_indent_x
        if sub_bg_right > width:
            sub_bg_right = width
        sub_bg_top = height - len(subtitles) * 2 * font.size - sub_indent_x
        draw.rectangle(((0, sub_bg_top), (sub_bg_right, height)), fill = sub_bg_colour)    

        # add subtitles
        sub_indent_y = height
        for subtitle in reversed(subtitles):  
            sub_indent_y -=  2 * font.size
            draw.text((sub_indent_x, sub_indent_y), subtitle, sub_colour, font = font)

        with PIL.Image.open(image_filename) as img:
            img = img.resize((width, height), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)    
            img = img.convert("RGBA")

            # composite the two images together and save
            temp_image_filename \
                = os.path.join(temp_folder, 
                               os.path.basename(image_filename) + '_with_subs.png')
            with PIL.Image.alpha_composite(img, img2) as img_full:
                img_full.save(temp_image_filename) 
            return temp_image_filename   

# The main function. It creates the video with all audio files of a given directory
# All images with given extensions from the same directory are fetched. 
# While an audio track is being played, one image, with the subtitles, is shown.
# Images are shown in alphabetic order. 
# Audio tracks are sorted using 'func_sort_audio_files'
# Descriptions and subtitles are obtained using 'func_get_audio_description_subtitles'
# Outputs: a compilation video 
#          a text file that contains the description of the tracks that constitute the video
def make_video( directory_name, 
                func_get_audio_description_subtitles,
                video_title = None,
                artist_override = None,
                func_sort_audio_files = default_func_sort_audio_files,
                width = 1280, 
                height = 720, 
                sub_font_size = 32,
                sub_font_name = "/System/Library/Fonts/SFNSText.ttf", 
                sub_encoding = "unic", 
                sub_colour = (255, 255, 255),
                # 4th number in sub_bg_colour is for the degree of transparency, 0 - 255 range
                sub_bg_colour = (0, 0, 0, 128), 
                sub_indent_x = 10,
                description_intro = [''],
                file_encoding = 'utf-8', 
                image_extensions = ['jpg', 'png'],
                audio_extensions = ['mp3', 'wav'], 
                dry_run = False):

    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    # prepare the temp directory
    temp_folder = os.path.join(directory_name, 'temp')
    if not os.path.exists(temp_folder):
        os.makedirs(temp_folder)
    extensions_to_remove = image_extensions + audio_extensions
    if not dry_run:
        extensions_to_remove += ['mp4']
    filenames_to_remove = get_filenames_with_extensions_recursively(temp_folder, extensions_to_remove)
    for fn in filenames_to_remove:
        os.remove(fn)

    # get the filenames and sort them
    images_filenames = get_filenames_with_extensions_recursively(directory_name, image_extensions)
    images_filenames.sort() 
    audio_filenames =  get_filenames_with_extensions_recursively(directory_name, audio_extensions)
    audio_filenames.sort(key = lambda af: func_sort_audio_files(af))

    # initiate variables                 
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    font = PIL.ImageFont.truetype(sub_font_name, sub_font_size, encoding = sub_encoding)  
    silent_video_name = os.path.join(temp_folder, os.path.basename(directory_name) + '_silent.mp4')
    video = cv2.VideoWriter(silent_video_name, fourcc, 1.0, (width, height))

    descriptions = description_intro
    audio = pydub.AudioSegment.silent(duration = 0)
    counter_audio = 0
    counter_seconds = 0

    for audio_name in audio_filenames:

        audio_mediainfo = {}
        try:
            audio_mediainfo = pydub.utils.mediainfo(audio_name).get('TAG', None)   
        except:
            pass

        if not ('title' in audio_mediainfo):
            track_name = os.path.basename(audio_name)
            # remove the extension
            track_name = track_name[:track_name.rfind('.')]
            audio_mediainfo['title'] = track_name

        if not ('artist' in audio_mediainfo):
            audio_mediainfo['artist'] = ''
        if (artist_override != None):  
            audio_mediainfo['artist'] = artist_override

        counter_audio += 1
        description, subtitles = func_get_audio_description_subtitles(counter_audio, audio_mediainfo)
        descriptions += [str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=counter_seconds)) + " " + description]

        if not dry_run:               
            image_filename = images_filenames[counter_audio % len(images_filenames)]             
            temp_image_filename = add_subtitles(  image_filename, 
                                                  temp_folder,
                                                  width, 
                                                  height, 
                                                  subtitles, 
                                                  font, 
                                                  sub_colour, 
                                                  sub_bg_colour, 
                                                  sub_indent_x)
            img2 = cv2.imread(temp_image_filename)
        else:
            img2 = None

        audio_piece = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3(audio_name)        
        limit_audio_length_so_far = counter_seconds + audio_piece.duration_seconds
        while (counter_seconds <= limit_audio_length_so_far):
            if not dry_run:
                # add the image to the video using PIL (adding by 1sec-long frames)  
                video.write(img2) 
            counter_seconds += 1

        if not dry_run: 
            audio += audio_piece
            # match the duration of audio and video so far
            audio += pydub.AudioSegment.silent(duration =  (counter_seconds * 1000.0 - len(audio))) 

    # Finalize the silent video              
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    video.release()

    # Define the filenames
    if video_title == None:
        video_title = os.path.basename(directory_name)
    descriptions_file_path = os.path.join(temp_folder, video_title + '.txt')
    compilation_audio_name = os.path.join(temp_folder, video_title + '.mp3')
    video_name             = os.path.join(temp_folder, video_title + '.mp4')
    ffmpeg_output_path     = os.path.join(temp_folder, video_title + '_ffmpeg.txt')

    if not dry_run:
        # dump the long mp3
        audio.export(compilation_audio_name, format = "mp3")   

        # combine audio and silent video into the final video
        ffmpeg_cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "' + silent_video_name + '" -i "' + compilation_audio_name \
                + '" -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k "' + video_name + '"' \
                + ' > "'+ ffmpeg_output_path + '" 2>&1'
        os.system(ffmpeg_cmd)   

    # Finalize and output the descriptions
    descriptions_len = 0
    for d_line in descriptions:
        descriptions_len += len(d_line)
    separator = "*" * 80    
    descriptions = [separator, 
                     "Directory: " + directory_name,
                     separator] \
                 + descriptions \
                 + [separator, 
                    "The length of the video is " + str(counter_seconds / 60.0) + " minute(s)",
                    "It should be under 202-205min (this is a pydub limitation)",
                    separator,
                    "Description is " + str(descriptions_len) + " characters long",
                    "It should be under 4500-5000 characters long (this is a youtube limitation)",
                    separator,
                    "Started " + str(start_time) + ", completed " + str(datetime.datetime.now()),
                    separator]
    for d_line in descriptions:
        print (d_line)
    with codecs.open(descriptions_file_path, 'w', encoding = file_encoding) as the_file:
        the_file.writelines(d_line + "\n" for d_line in (descriptions))

def get_audio_description_subtitles_simple(counter_audio, audio_mediainfo):
    title = audio_mediainfo['title'].strip().replace('\\', '')
    track_name = 'Track ' + str(counter_audio) + ": " + title
    artist_name = audio_mediainfo['artist'].strip()
    desc = track_name + " by " + artist_name
    return desc, [track_name, artist_name]

def dry_run_get_audio_description_subtitles_dry_run(counter_audio, audio_mediainfo):
    print(audio_mediainfo)   
    return "", ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_video(   directory_name = os.path.expanduser('~/Music/LouisXIII copy'), 
                  #artist_override = 'Dalida',
                  func_get_audio_description_subtitles = get_audio_description_subtitles_simple,
                  description_intro = ['Intended for personal use. I own the CDs', ''],
                  dry_run = True)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import os, codecs, datetime, glob

E401 multiple imports on one line
```

Recommend you run [`$ flake8`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) and heed its advice,
as [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) asks for just one import per line.
Use [`isort`](https://pypi.org/project/isort/) to organize them.

Each of your functions has lovely comments; thank you.
Recommend you turn the one-sentence comments into docstrings.

The `add_subtitles()` function is maybe slightly long,
and could be broken out into one or two helpers.
The arg list is on the long side.
`Width` + `height` could trivially be collapsed into `size`,
but I wonder if some of the other attributes, like colour,
might sensibly be defaulted from an object that has an `add_subtitles()` method.

```
        if max_length_subtitles < sub_size[0]:
            max_length_subtitles = sub_size[0]
```

A more pythonic way to express this would be to
construct a list of font sizes, and then
assign `max( ... )` of those sizes.

Similarly, please assign `sub_bg_right` as `max` of two numbers.

It feels like much of this logic could sensibly be encapsulated
within a `sub_bg` object.

```
        draw.text(..., font = font)
```

PEP-8 asks for spaces around `=` assignment, but no spaces around `=` keyword args: `font=font`.

Nice comments on `make_video()`.
Again, it takes quite a few args.
It feels like a subtitle object could encapsulate several of them.
These args are trouble:

```
            description_intro = [''],
            file_encoding = 'utf-8', 
            image_extensions = ['jpg', 'png'],
            audio_extensions = ['mp3', 'wav'],
```

Well, file_encoding is fine, just lose the extra blanks around `=` equals.
But the lists are trouble.
Now, I know you're not mutating them.
But it's a [gotcha](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/), evaluating and binding a mutable list at function definition time.
Don't get in the habit of doing that.
Make it default to an immutable sequence, such as a (tuple),
or use the usual idiom:

```
def foo(name, extensions=None):
    if extensions is None:
        extensions = ['jpg', 'png']
```

The point is to re-evaluate the assignment on each execution of `foo()`,
rather than binding an immortal list just once.

```
if not os.path.exists(temp_folder):
    os.makedirs(temp_folder)
```

Feel free to save one line by specifying [`, exist_ok=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs).

You could easily break out a few helpers from this function,
for example the whole `audio_filenames` loop is naturally a helper function.

```
    if not ('artist' in audio_mediainfo):
```

That's fine, but testing `if 'artist' not in audio_mediainfo:` is
slightly more pythonic.

```
    if (artist_override != None):
```

1. No need for `(` extra parens `)` in a python `if`.
2. Please test `is` identity of the `None` singleton, rather than equality: `if artist_override is not None:`. Or, more simply: `if artist_override:`

   ```
   while (counter_seconds <= limit_audio_length_so_far):
   ```

No `(` extra parens `)` in a python `while`, please.

```
if video_title == None:
```

Please test `is None`.

```
                "It should be under 202-205min (this is a pydub limitation)",
                ...
                "It should be under 4500-5000 characters long (this is a youtube limitation)",
```

There are limits, but you're not telling me what they are.
Put a stake in the ground, say 202 min. and 4500 char. and be done with it.

```
title = audio_mediainfo['title'].strip().replace('\\', '')
```

This is apparently sanitizing a filename, making it safe to open for write.
That is, you are rejecting Known Bad unicode code points.
I would be more convinced if you instead used [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to
accept Known Good characters.

You tend to accommodate long expressions with `\` backwhack continuation characters.
Consider using `(` parens `)` instead:

```
short_string = 'Hi!'
much_longer_string = ('This,'
                      ' that,'
                      ' and the other.')
```